# Fetching only selected values from CrossSelect of Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jakarta-ee

In below screen shot there are 2 boxes where user will select from left box to right which ever items he want. Now which ever the column selected by the user in the right box. I need only those items.. 
Below is the screen shot and code.In the below screen shot 
i need to get only one,two and three values from right box.So, how to get only selected items from the right box?

To Fetch the right box values is this the right menthod in JavaScript Function. Please help

```
function export()
    {                 
         <%if(request.getParameter("myServersID1") != null)
        {
              String[] ItemNames;
```

ItemNames =   request.getParameterValues("myServersID1");

```
              for(int i = 0; i < ItemNames.length; i++)

              {
                     String selecteditems;

                     selecteditems= ItemNames[i];

                   System.out.println("selecteditems" +selecteditems);

        }}%>

        alert("selectcol"); 

    }
```

when button is added

```
<input type="button" value="Export" class="btn-arrow-pri btn-small" style="margin-left: 300px;" onclick="export();"/>
```

__*_*      ***_*___**

```
four   |    |

       |>   |one

five   |<   |two

       | >> |three

       |<<  |
```

### ***_*___**

CODE is:

```
<html>
[...]
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function moveRight(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myserversID option:selected").appendTo("#myserversID1")
        });
    }

    function moveLeft(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myserversID1 option:selected").appendTo("#myserversID")
        });
    }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<select size="8" id="myserversID" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option value="four">four</option>
    <option value="five">five</option>
    <option value="six">six</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Move Right" onclick="moveRight();"/>
<input type="button" value="Move Left" onclick="moveLeft();"/>
<select size="8" id="myserversID1" multiple="multiple">  
</select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly next time and get rid of un-needed parts like the `meta` attributes

Comment: ok, Colossos, Next time i format. Can u please help me in finding the answer for the above query.